# Node.js eventemitter subscriptions on multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a hard time understanding why this is so complicated, so I'm suspecting I'm doing something very wrong.  Say I have two controllers that look something like this.  They're nearly clones in regards to endpoints, but not in operation -- kind of like interface implementations

```
(function(someController){
    //some require statements
    var importantEvent = require("../Connectors/SaveEvents");

    someController.init = function(app){
        //app.get, app.post, etc etc etc
        app.post('/saveThat', function(req, res){
            //do some stuff

            importantEvent.Saved({ from: "someController", data: stuff });
        });
    }

    importantEvent.on('Saved', function(data){
        //let this guy know it happened then do some stuff
    })
})(module.exports);
```

Ok? ok.  My event emitter thing that doesn't work and I suspect is very wrong looks like this... (SaveEvents.js)

```
(function(ImportantEvent){

    var util = require('util');
    var eventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

    eventEmitter.call(ImportantEvent);  //??? is this needed?

    ImportantEvent.Saved = function(origin, dataPayload) {
        //maybe do some stuff to the data
        var self = this;
        self.emit('Saved', { from: origin, data: dataPayload });
    };

    util.inherits(OAuthEvents, eventEmitter);

})(module.exports);
```

when I use grunt, I get a no-go

```
c:\projects\srsly\node\someController.js:21
        importantEvent.on('Saved', function(data){
                       ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

Got an idea why or how to better go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem you're experiencing is due to how you are setting up your event emitter. The `on` function is part of the prototype of the `EventEmitter` That means you need to create an instance of it, not just invoke the constructor on an object you already have. If you rewrite your `ImportantEvent` as follows, you should get the `on` function and possibly the rest of your stuff will start to work:

```
module.exports = (function(eve){
    var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
    var ImportantEvent = new EventEmitter();

    ImportantEvent.Saved = function(origin, dataPayload) {
        this.emit('Saved', {from: origin, data:dataPayload});
    };

    return ImportantEvent;
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work as you want. Keep in mind that module.exports will be cached and when you run `require('ImportantEvent')` at second time you'll get the previously initialised instance (singleton)

```
var inherits = require('util').inherits,
    EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function ImportantEvent(){}

inherits(ImportantEvent, EventEmitter);

ImportantEvent.prototype.Saved = function(){}

module.exports = new ImportantEvent();
```